# How to retain CSS transform scale on checked state

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I'm looking for a simple CSS-only way of creating a `:hover` `scale` transformation that retains its scale based on `:checked` state. Here's what I'm after:

[image]

Currently, itemB in my example has a `scale(2)` on `:hover`, which works fine. My problem is that I can't seem to come up with a **CSS-only** way of retaining scale when the item is `checked` (these icons are backed by hidden radio buttons).

Here's the HTML structure I'm working with:

```
...
<ul>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" id="itemA" />
        <label class="icon" for="itemA">
            <img src="..." />
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" id="itemB" />
        <label class="icon" for="itemB">
            <img src="..." />
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" id="itemC" />
        <label class="icon" for="itemC">
            <img src="..." />
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
...
```

and my CSS:

```
li input[type="radio"] + label img {
    width: 50px;
    margin: 50% auto;
    transition: all .3s;
}

li:hover input[type="radio"] + label img {
    transform: scale(2);
}
```

I thought the easiest approach would be to add another selector for the checked state:

```
li input[type="radio"]:checked + label img {
    transform: scale(2);
}
```

But that doesn't seem to work, and I can't figure out why. Any thoughts? Please, no jQuery or other JS suggestions. I'm trying to accomplish this simple effect using only CSS3. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you show us a demo please? The selector that you've given at last should work fine.

Comment: Dammit. I DOES work! I just wasted hours trying to figure out why, and it turns out that it was a server caching issue (even though I've configured it to NOT cache). Sorry, for the bother. And thanks to those who tried to help me. This is a non-issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Checked state

Adding the checked state to the input element should maintain the scale on the image.
Checked code:

```
 li input[type="radio"]:checked + label img {
  transform: scale(2);
  transform-origin: center left;
}
```

---

#### Example fiddle:

```css
ul {} li input[type="radio"] + label img {
  width: 50px;
  transition: all .3s;
}
li:hover input[type="radio"] + label img {
  transform: scale(2);
  transform-origin: center left;
}
li input[type="radio"]:checked + label img {
  transform: scale(2);
  transform-origin: center left;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="itemA" />
    <label class="icon" for="itemA">
      <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/50/50" />
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="itemB" />
    <label class="icon" for="itemB">
      <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/50/50" />
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="itemC" />
    <label class="icon" for="itemC">
      <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/50/50" />
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. It turns out I was just running into caching issues. And the :checked scale actually does work. I'll mark your answer as correct since you basically confirmed what I already had. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your scale in the second block is also 2. I tried this with scale 1 for li input[type="radio"]:checked + label img and it worked.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I was more of a mistake on my part (with caching). The original scale(2) does indeed work.